# Convert SQL query to Linq (Need help to write sql query to linq)

Tags: sql, linq

This is my query returns me accurate result that I want. I want to write this in LINQ.

```
select i.reportdate,co.naam,i.issueid,i.vrijetekst,i.lockuser,te.teamnaam, count(ie.issueid) as events, sum(ie.bestedetijd) as Tijd  
            from company co,hoofdcontracten hc,subcontracten sc,sonderhoud so,g2issues i,g2issueevents ie, g2issuestatus iss,teams te,locatie l 
            Where co.companyid = hc.companyid And 
            hc.hcontractid = sc.hcontractid and 
            so.scontractid = sc.scontractid and 
            sc.scontractid = i.scontractid and 
            i.issueid = ie.issueid and 
            so.teamid = te.teamid and 
            ie.locatieid = l.locatieid and 
            l.bezoek = 0 and 
            i.issuestatusid = iss.issuestatusid and 
            fase < 7 and 
           co.companyid <> 165 
           group by i.reportdate,co.naam,i.issueid,i.vrijetekst,i.lockuser,te.teamnaam ,i.reportdate
           having sum(ie.bestedetijd)>123
```

I am trying this but confused at select clause. How can I use aggregate function in select clause and group by clause also.

```
var myList = (from co in _context.Company
                          from hc in _context.Hoofdcontracten
                          from sc in _context.Subcontracten
                          from so in _context.Sonderhoud
                          from i in _context.G2issues
                          from ie in _context.G2issueEvents
                          from iss in _context.G2issueStatus
                          from te in _context.Teams
                          from l in _context.Locatie
                          where
                          co.CompanyId == hc.CompanyId
                          && hc.HcontractId == sc.HcontractId
                          && so.ScontractId == sc.ScontractId
                          && sc.ScontractId == i.ScontractId
                          && i.IssueId == ie.IssueId
                          && so.Teamid == te.Teamid
                          && ie.LocatieId == l.LocatieId
                          && l.Bezoek == false
                          && i.IssuestatusId == iss.IssueStatusId
                          && iss.Fase < 7
                          && co.CompanyId != 165
                          select new { }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

My! Someone was trying to save a few minutes typing time using all kinds of undecipherable variable names like hc, sc, so, i, ie, iss, without bothering that this would tenfold the time needed to understand what happens.

I haven't tried to decipher your query fully, apparently you thought it was not needed to show your entity framework classes and relation between them.

What I gather is that you want to perform a big join and then select several columns from the join. You want to group the resulting collection into groups of items that have the same reportdate, name, issueid, .... You want the bestede tijd on all items in each group, and you want the number of items in the group

LINQ has two types of syntaxes which in fact do the same: [Query syntax and Method syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq). Although I can read the query syntax, I'm more familiar with the method syntax, so my answer will be using the method syntax. I guess you'll understand what happens.

I'll do it in smaller steps, you can concatenate all steps into one if you want.

First you do a big join, after which you select some columns. A big join is one of the few statements that are easier when written in query syntax (See [SO: LINQ method syntax for multiple left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597876/linq-method-syntax-for-multiple-left-join))

```
var bigJoin = from hc in _context.Hoofdcontracten
              from sc in _context.Subcontracten
              from so in _context.Sonderhoud
              ...
              from l in _context.Locatie
              where
              co.CompanyId == hc.CompanyId
              && hc.HcontractId == sc.HcontractId
              ...
              && iss.Fase < 7
              && co.CompanyId != 165
              select new
              {
                  hc,
                  sc,
                  so,
                  ... // etc select only items you'll use to create your end result
               };
```

Now you've got a big table with the join results. You want to divide this table into groups with the same value for

```
{
    i.reportdate,
    co.naam,
    i.issueid,
    i.vrijetekst,
    i.lockuser,
    te.teamnaam,
}
```

(by the way: you mentioned reportdate twice in your GroupBy, I guess that's not what you meant)

This grouping is done using [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var groups = bigjoin.GroupBy(joinedItem => new
    {   // the items to group on: all elements in the group have the same values
        ReportDate = i.Reportdate,
        CompanyName = co.naam,
        IssueId = i.issueid,
        FreeText = i.vrijetekst,
        LockUser = i.lockuser,
        TeamName = te.teamnaam,
    });
```

The result is a collection of groups. Each group contains the original bigJoin items that have the same value for for ReportDate, CompanyName, etc. This common value is in group.Key

Now from every group you want the following items:

- Several of the common values in the group (ReportDate, CompanyName, IssueId, ...). We get them from the Key of the group
- Tijd = the sum of ie.bestedeTijd of all elements in the group
- Events = is the number of ie.IssueId of all elements in the group. As every element in the group has only one ie.IssueId, the result is also the number of elements in the group.

From this result, you only want to keep those with a Tijd > 123

So we'll do a new select on the groups, followed by a Where on Tijd

```
var result = groups.Select(group => new
 {
     Tijd = group.Sum(groupElement => groupElement.ie.bestedetijd),
     Events = group.Count(),

     // the other fields can be taken from the key
     ReportDate = group.Key.reportdate,
     CompanyName = group.Key.CompanyName,
     IssueId = group.Key.Issueid,
     FreeText = group.Key.FreeText,
     LockUser = group.Key.LockUser,
     TeamName = group.Key.TeamName, 
})
.Where(resultItem => resultItem.Tijd > 123);
```